# Is it possible that there is a world ruled by a single nation?

Tags: united-nations

I am developing the global context about my game and I realize that I only developed one nation. I want to show the planet as a unit to counter against the divine side *(there is a kind of strange plant God)*. But the question arose if it is possible that something like this existed, as humans we always tend to divide ourselves, which makes me want to add one more nation.

What should I do?

Comment: Well, according to almost every interplanetary SF ever, yes it's possible... but you're also running into [Planet of Hats](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlanetOfHats), which you should probably read.

Comment: There are so many different ways that this could happen, that I think your question needs to provide some specific constraints. How human-like does your species need to be? Are hive-mind things out? How similar in thinking does your species have to be? What if the species was just one huge contiguous organism? Let us know what _specifically_ you're looking for and then you can get more targeted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, it is impossible for an entire world to be ruled by a single nation.

A nation is defined as a large group of people who have many cultural factors in common and are culturally different from people who are outside the group, and who feel that they are a nationality or ethic group or nation separate from all other groups.

So by definition a national government rules over a territory occupied by a majority that are members of one national group, plus usually members of a few minority groups.  And if ever a nation manages to lose all members of minority groups, because they successfully revolt against that nation, or because they are exterminated, or all emigrate to other nations, or all gradually assimilate into the majority, that will not last.  Even if some nation achieves a population with 100 percent majority nationality, that will not last forever.  Over time minor differences between different segments of the population will grow larger and larger, and people will care more and more about those differences, until the people of a once homogeneous nation now feel like they are members of two or more ethnic groups and nationalities instead of one.

If there is a government ruling over an entire planet with a population of hundreds of millions or billions, it is likely to rule over tens or hundreds or thousands of ethnic groups who all consider themselves to be separate nationalities and nations, and thus be much more like an empire than a nation.  If the people of that empire feel loyalty to it, that loyalty will be more like imperialism, empire loyalty, than like patriotism, loyalty to a nation.

Answer (score 8):

There were times in our own history when "the world" really seemed to almost be taken over by a single nation. Every time it was a bunch of people who were under the banner of one empire that was as wide as its denizens thought to be the whole of the world. Yet not a single one got to dominate even just all places inhabited by people. They would just call those outside their domain "barbarians" and call it a day.

Some examples of such empires and their rulers:

- The Greek under Alexander the Great
- Medieval Europe under Charlemagne
- Medieval Europe under the pope as well, as popes had power greater than kings for a long while
- Asia under Kublai Khan

So maybe it comes down to your world having some imperialistic nation that went on a roll conquering others, but they don't have the technology to map the world much beyond their borders so the head of state thinks they rule the planet alone.

Comment: Can you add China to your list of examples? Through large parts of their history China was unified and from Chinese perspective China was the entire world.

Comment: Example with Charlemange is so much wrong. In his time there was still independent Pope, independent christan rulers in British Isles, very much civilized andalusians in Iberia, extremly independent and civilized Byzantium and bunch of other independent states.

Comment: @quarague I did, China was where Kublai Khan had his seat of power

Answer (score 4):

Humans tend to divide, unless confronted with a sufficient Other to bind us together. You say there's a divine plant thing that needs balancing. A plant with deity powers sure seems like a motivation for humanity to band together.

Now, the real question is time period. The world being under a single government is conditional upon one key thing: speed of communication. If you cannot communicate the will of the central authority out to the tips of the empire (and get replies back) with regularity and speed, the empire will fracture. At various points in time, new communication techs appeared and the average size of nations increased in those times. The US central government in Washington became significantly more involved in California with the advent of the telegraph, for example.

So, yes, single world government appears to be plausible given human history, but only with a sufficient threat to band us together and with communication infrastructure to bind us under one flag.

Answer (score 2):

As humans, we do have a natural tendency to divide "us" and "them" when it comes to social groups. I remember reading somewhere (some time ago, not sure if I can still find the exact article) that while humans are social creatures, we are adapted to small social groups and tend to get overwhelmed by huge crowds such as those found in metropolitan cities. That is why there is that tendency to think that people get "colder" and more distant the larger the city gets, because they retreat and keep to themselves more as a defense mechanism.

You didn't specify the species, but I believe it would be better if you created beings that are naturally evolved to live in large cooperative societies, with less defensive instincts among their own kind that would lead to possible infighting, and ideally some sort of evolutionary pressure that caused them to prefer collectively relying on each other for support and survival. It should be easier to form a global government with less risk of fracturing then.